# Setfacl in folders working but in files don't work correctly

Tags: linux, samba, setfacl

I have a file server running Samba 4.9 in Debian 11 the share folders is working.
I used setfacl for subgroups, so i had conclusion was confused and not working.
So i used setfacl for each user, in fact worked but just to folders, if create a document  defined to just read to another user, he get folder access  but seem empty. If i to give getfacl command show the user have read rights.
Anyone can explain for me, what to need to do?

I settings the share folder as show below:

```
mkdir /srv/shared
chown root.group1 /srv/shared
chmod -R 770 /srv/shared
setfacl -m u:user1:rwx shared
setfacl -m u:user2:rx shared
setfacl -m g:group1:rx shared
setfacl -m g::--- shared
setfacl -m d:u:user1:rwx shared
setfacl -m d:u:user2:rx shared
setfacl -m d:g:group1:rx shared
setfacl -m d:g::--- shared
```

Both user1 and user2 belong tho the group group1

When user1 create folder1 in shared, the user2 have access, but if user1 create a file1.txt the user2 don't see file1.txt, folder1 seem empty!

Thanks if someone had answer.

Comment: In my server there are various shared folders.
In this topic i show just one folder called "shared" with permissions to group group1, both user1 and user2 belong the same group1.
user1 logged  created file1.txt with permissions of inherited father folder (rwxrwx---), but when user2 make login don't see file1.txt but  was setting with command setfacl -m u:user2:rx file1.txt

Comment: The code you show depends on the current working directory. It is not shown.

Comment: Put amendments to your question in the question, not in the comments: Imagine that no one reads the comments.